# How to fix "Cannot resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)'"

Tags: java, android

i have a problem with my code :
Cannot resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, null)' 
. Can Anyone Help me to fix it ?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_profile:
                break;
            case R.id.btn_show_dialog:
                OptionDialogFragment mOptionDialogFragment = new OptionDialogFragment();

                FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                mOptionDialogFragment.show(mFragmentManager, OptionDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                break;
```

those are my imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

my OptionDialogFragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.app.DialogFragment;



public class OptionDialogFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnChoose, btnClose;
    RadioGroup rgOptions;
    RadioButton rbSaf, rbMou, rbLvg, rbMoyes;
    OnOptionDialogListener optionDialogListener;

    public OptionDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option_dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        btnChoose = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClose = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        rgOptions = view.findViewById(R.id.rg_options);
        rbSaf = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_saf);
        rbLvg = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_lvg);
        rbMou = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_mou);
        rbMoyes = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_moyes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Fragment fragment = getParentFragment();

        if (fragment instanceof DetailCategoryFragment) {
            DetailCategoryFragment detailCategoryFragment = (DetailCategoryFragment) fragment;
            this.optionDialogListener = detailCategoryFragment.optionDialogListener;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.optionDialogListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_close:
                getDialog().cancel();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_choose:
                int checkedRadioButtonId = rgOptions.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if (checkedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                    String coach = null;
                    switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {
                        case R.id.rb_saf:
                            coach = rbSaf.getText().toString().trim();
                            break;

                        case R.id.rb_mou:
                            coach = rbMou.getText().toString().trim();
                            break;

                        case R.id.rb_lvg:
                            coach = rbLvg.getText().toString().trim();
                            break;

                        case R.id.rb_moyes:
                            coach = rbMoyes.getText().toString().trim();
                            break;
                    }

                    if (optionDialogListener != null) {
                        optionDialogListener.onOptionChosen(coach);
                    }
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public interface OnOptionDialogListener {
        void onOptionChosen(String text);
    }
}
```

and in OptionDialogFragment there is a problem that is getDialog() 'Cannot resolve method 'getDialog ()' and why  why getDialog () has a problem, is there an import that is still lacking?

Comment: We don't know what your `OptionDialogFragment` looks like and what kind of `show()` methods it has, but apparently there's none that you can call as in `mOptionDialogFragment.show(mFragmentManager, OptionDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());` with the class name being `null`. You could edit the question and add the `OptionDialogFragment`. But do you understand the basic meaning of the error message? I.e. the method signature doesn't match. The `show()` is expecting different parameters than what you are giving to it.

Comment: Maybe it's even possible that it's expecting a different `FragmentManager` from a different version of `android.support`, but it might be that you would then get a `ClassCastException` instead. I'm not sure, actually.

Comment: I have added OptionDialogFragment, please help me find a solution

Comment: You have `OptionDialogFragment extends Fragment` but the the `Fragment` class doesn't have a `getDialog()` method. Maybe you meant `OptionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment` instead(?)

Comment: That's right, thanks bro, 
I should use OptionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment, but in my code is OptionDialogFragment extends Fragment

Answer (score 0):

look at `function public void onAttach(), optionDialogListener not yet declared in detailcategoryfragment.java`.

First, you must create `optiondialoglistener` in `detailcategoryfragment`